# Lengths of series not matching for np.where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe, MSYs_init, that contains an existing column "Start Date" with about 250 values.  I want to take the year from that column's dates and match it to the year in a series of grant start dates.  Please see below, as I believe I have overcomplicated things and cannot get the solution through Google-fu.

```
MSYs_init['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(MSYs_init['Start Date'], errors='coerce')
VISTAMbrStartYr = pd.DatetimeIndex(MSYs_init['Start Date']).year


VISTAGrantYrStarts = pd.Series(['2020, 8, 17','2019, 8, 18', '2018, 8, 19', '2017, 9, 17'])
VISTAGrantYrStarts = pd.to_datetime(VISTAGrantYrStarts, errors='coerce')
VISTAGrantYr = pd.DatetimeIndex(VISTAGrantYrStarts).year  

MSYs_init['VISTA Grant Year'] = np.where(VISTAMbrStartYr == VISTAGrantYr, VISTAGrantYrStarts, np.nan)
```

This is my error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-27a1a1454145> in <module>
     12 VISTAGrantYr = pd.DatetimeIndex(VISTAGrantYrStarts).year
     13 
---> 14 MSYs_init['Mbr Starting Grant Yr'] = np.where((VISTAMbrStartYr == VISTAGrantYr) &
     15                                               (VISTAMbrStartMoDay >= VISTAGrantYrStartMoDay),
     16                                               VISTAMbrStartYr,VISTAMbrStartYr-1) 

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in cmp_method(self, other)
    100         if isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, Index, ABCSeries)):
    101             if other.ndim > 0 and len(self) != len(other):
--> 102                 raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
    103 
    104         if is_object_dtype(self) and not isinstance(self, ABCMultiIndex):

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: `VISTAMbrStartYr` and `VISTAGrantYr` have different lengths. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited the above and am sure my methodology is wrong.  I want a new column to reflect VISTAGrantYrStarts that have a year in VISTAGrantYr that matches the year in VISTAMbrStartYr, otherwise nothing.

Comment: You need the function `.isin()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to achieve can be done with the following:

```
MSYs_init['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(MSYs_init['Start Date'], errors='coerce')
VISTAGrantYrStarts = pd.to_datetime(VISTAGrantYrStarts, errors='coerce')
VISTAGrantYr = VISTAGrantYrStarts.year
MSYs_init['VISTA Grand Year'] = np.where(MSYs_init['Start Date'].dt.year.isin(VISTAGrantYr),
                                         MSYs_init['Start Date'].dt.year,
                                         np.nan)
```

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3],
                 'dates':['2019-02-20','2019-02-21','2020-02-21','2021-02-20']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'],errors='coerce')
aux = pd.to_datetime(['2017-02-20','2018-02-21','2019-02-21','2019-02-20'],errors='coerce').year
df['dates_2'] = np.where(df['dates'].dt.year.isin(aux),df['dates'].dt.year,np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   index      dates  dates_2
0      0 2019-02-20   2019.0
1      1 2019-02-21   2019.0
2      2 2020-02-21      NaN
3      3 2021-02-20      NaN
```

@Celius, I need it to return the VISTAGrantYrStarts, not "Start Date", and so when I try to do this, it doesn't work.

```
MSYs_init['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(MSYs_init['Start Date'],errors='coerce')
GrantStarts = pd.to_datetime(['2017-02-20','2018-02-21','2019-02-21','2019-02-20'],errors='coerce').year
MSYs_init['Mbr Grant Start'] = np.where(MSYs_init['Start Date'].dt.year.isin(GrantStarts),GrantStarts.dt.year,np.nan)
MSYs_init.head(50)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-52fd06b959bf> in <module>
      1 MSYs_init['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(MSYs_init['Start Date'],errors='coerce')
      2 GrantStarts = pd.to_datetime(['2017-02-20','2018-02-21','2019-02-21','2019-02-20'],errors='coerce').year
----> 3 MSYs_init['Mbr Grant Start'] = np.where(MSYs_init['Start Date'].dt.year.isin(GrantStarts),GrantStarts.dt.year,np.nan)
      4 MSYs_init.head(50)

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Comment: that threw this error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: The isin might be helpful, though.  I would like to do this:

Comment: MSYs_init['VISTA Grant Year'] = np.where(VISTAMbrStartYr.isin(VISTAGrantYr),
                                         VISTAGrantYrStarts,
                                         np.nan)

Comment: Yes, I forgot you had a variable already defined withe `.year`

Comment: But that gives me this error:  "invalid type promotion"

Comment: But is MSYs_init['Start Date'] a datetime series?

Comment: Should be, per this line of code above: 

MSYs_init['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(MSYs_init['Start Date'], errors='coerce')

Comment: Try the full code above plese and let me know if it works.

Comment: That's why I updated the code, I'm no longer making it a datetime index

Comment: No, I'm getting the same "Series object has not attribute..." error:

Comment: Bloody me, I was missing `.dt` for the Series. it should be good now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't think it is the right thing, why would you want to return a series? It is conceptually wrong. Plus, if you wish to return the match, then both will be the same. Could you add an expected output? What would the ideal output be from my example?